# Is there a way to programmatically copy the text and format of an Excel cell and paste it to a RichTextBox?

Tags: excel, vb.net, richtextbox

If I CTRL+C from the cell and then CTRL+V on the RTB then it works fine, but I cannot find a way of doing this with code.  I cannot find a type of variable where to store the formated contents of the Excel cell.

Of course, I have added the references to Microsoft Excel 15.0, etc. and I get the Excel data with "workshhet.cells(x,y).value" since I cannot find any other method.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't store it in a variable. Let the existing copy/paste functionality handle it. I'm not sure how to copy something to the Clipboard using Excel Automation but I would suggest that you search for that. You can then call the `Paste` method of your `RichTextBox` and it will retrieve the data from the Clipboard automatically.

Comment: If all you want is the formatted text value (as seen in Excel), use the Range.Text property.  If you also need style information (font, color, etc.), things get a bit more complicated to retrieve this information.  Or you can go the Clipboard route as mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: Thank you, guys.  Since what I need is text with style, color, etc. I will have to explore the Clipboard way, because when done by hand it works perfectly.

Comment: At the end it's as simkple as 'worksheet.Cells(2, 2).Copy
        RichTextBox1.Paste()'